# Regex to check the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000` - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the date string of the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000`

Eg: `2000-01-01T00:00:00.000`

I need a regex to check if given string is of the above format. I have tried the regex

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})Z$
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've added `Z` in regex, but examples doesn't contain them.

Comment: The regex does not match the desired format? Also regex won't be enough to validate the format as `9999-99-99T99:99:99.999` would be a valid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the regex AND the date produced

```js
const simplifiedPattern = /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z)$/
const testData = ["2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "2000-01-01 00:00:00.000Z"]
const matches = testData.filter(e => simplifiedPattern.test(e))

console.log(matches)

matches.forEach(match => {
  const d = new Date(match)
  console.log(match === d.toISOString())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is missing `Z` and you forgot about matching 3 last zeros after `.` (dot needs to be escaped):

```regex
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z)$
```

```js
const simplifiedPattern = /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z)$/
const testData = ["2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "2000-01-01 00:00:00.000Z"]
const matches = testData.filter(e => simplifiedPattern.test(e))

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: `9999-99-99T99:99:99.999Z` would still be a valid value?